# IBM WebSphere JAX-RPC Client Compression

Tags: java, web-services, compression, websphere, jax-rpc

Does anyone know where I can find documentation to support compression of JAX-RPC web service requests from a client using client-side handlers?  I'm looking to compress requests using gzip, and I tried,

```
SOAPMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "gzip")
```

but got the "java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: gzip" error.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

See com.ibm.websphere.webservices.http.requestContentEncoding in http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rwbs_httptransportprop.html - there's a http transport level property for outbound http requests